# Improve performance on parsing text file

Tags: java, parsing, text

First of all, sorry for my English and for the length of the message.

I'm writing a simple application in Java for visual cryptography for a school project that takes a schema File and a secret image, then creates n images using the information contained in the schema.

For each pixel in the secret image the application looks for a matrix in the schema file and write m pixels in the n shares (one row for each share).

A schema file contains the matrices (n*m) for every color needed for encoding and it is composed as follows

COLLECTION COLOR 1
START MATRIX 1
RGB
GBR
BGR
END
START MATRIX 2
.....
COLLECTION COLOR 2
START MATRIX 1
XXX
XXX
XXX
END
......
//

This file can be a few lines or many thousands so I can't save the matrices in the application, but I need to always read the file.

To test the performance I created a parser that simply search the matrix looking line by line, but it is very slow.

I thought I'd save the line number of each matrix and then use RandomAccessFile to read it but I wanted to know if there is a more powerful method for doing this.

Thanks

Comment: if many throusands is something like 500,000, and the average line length is 10 chars (20 bytes), that makes 10,000,000 bytes, which is only 10 MBs. And that's asuming you store the lines as is in memory, instead of using a compact binary representation. Why can't you read the matrix in memory, use it to create your N images, and then discard it? 10 MBs is nothing. And even if I'm one wrong by one order, 100 MBs is still nothing.

Comment: how big is this data? is loading the data in memory or using a least recently used cache an option here?

Comment: i can't read in memory mainly because it is one of the goals of the project, and then because the schema files may be large even hundreds of megabytes.

Comment: I'm still thinking about how to implement a cache because for example I have a test-schema with only 2 collections (for black and white) and around 30000 matrix and the matrix must be randomly selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are truly dealing with massive, massive input files that exceed your ability to load the entire thing into RAM, then using a persistent key/value store like [MapDB](https://github.com/jankotek/MapDB) may be an easy way to do this.  Parse the file once and build of an efficient [Collection+Color]->Matrix map.  Store that in a persistent HTree.  That'll take care of all of the caching, etc... for you.  Make sure to create a good hash function for the Collection+Color tuple, and it should be very performant.

If your data access pattern tends to clump together, it may be faster to store in a B+Tree index - you can play with that and see what works best.

Comment: Thanks, I tried MapDB with B+Tree and works very good, only for collections with more than 10000 matrices I get an error..
I have one map for each collection BTreeMap<Integer,String[]> but sometimes when invoking map.get(i) it return an Object and thus a ClassCastException.

Comment: OK - I'd think that you would want to map Integer->Matrix (not a string representation, but an actual usable object). If you want to post your code to the MapDB forum, I'm certain Jan can comment on it (or I will).  Getting an incorrect object back from MapDB can only happen if the deserialization is messing up, which seems pretty unlikely to be a library problem.

Answer (score 0):

For your schema file, use a `FileChannel` and call `.map()` on it. With a little effort, you can calculate the necessary offsets into the mapped representation of the file and use that, or even encapsulate this mapping into a custom structure.

Comment: Thanks, i will keep in mind. I have to do a bit of practice to use it well!